# Working with Ionic and Angular with different versions

Tags: angular, ionic4

Does Ionic 4 work with Angular version 2? In other words, do Ionic and Angular versions depend on each other?

Answer (score 0):

Each version of Ionic, just like any other project or application, has dependencies. These are the dependencies for Ionic v4:

```
"@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.901.1",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.14",
```

So yes, while Angular does not depend on Ionic, Ionic does depend on specific Angular versions as specified in the `package.json`

You can try and downgrade the Angular dependencies in `package.json` of Ionic, but that will likely cause build issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic framework uses Angular and provides additional components to specifically make your mobile app development easier. Ionic in turn relies on Angular  for some of it's functionality. Certain Ionic versions only support some particular Angular Version. For eg: Ionic 1 support Angular JS only.

Why latest Angular in Ionic?

Latest Angular version has lot of features and changes(for eg : LazyLoading), which in turn affect app's performance e.t.c.Even some Plugins also depends on Angular version. So I prefer to use latest Angular for latest Ionic versions.